How to find how many parameters of a conditional statement are met?
I am dealing with an issue where I have to return the number of parameters in a conditional statement that are met. Further, I can only use more conditional statements and the return function.
The only way I could think to solve this was creating a for loop that iterates over the parameters, however, I must do this without using loops.

You can use some() method and check against the parameters

It's ok to post school questions, but we do require that you make an attempt and post what you've tried and not just expect that we'll just write you up an answer.

In JavaScript, booleans act like 1 or 0 when you add them together.
Wrap each condition in parentheses, then add all the conditions. Your type checker will yell at you but it works.
(x > 3) + (y < 5)
// 0 if they are both false
// 1 if one condition is true
// 2 if they are both true

